# Calculate the probability that poisoned the man and his wife

Tags: probability

Ten pieces of candy, including three pieces corrupt. Eat four pieces man and his wife ate six pieces, the possibility that the man and his wife poisoned

Comment: None. The man loves his wife and would never hurt her.

Comment: Question solved.

Comment: Users should post something constructive, to provide at least some evidence that they have worked on the question and give some idea of their level of math background, and not use this site as a homework answering service.

Comment: Why would they set up an exercise like this? Its a bit, you know, dark.

Comment: @Mike How can you be so sure?

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the probability that only one of them is poisoned.   This is the probability that the man eats all poisoned  pieces plus the probability that the wife eats all poisoned pieces, which is

$$\frac{7}{\binom{10}{4}} + \frac{\binom {7}{3}}{\binom {10}{6}} = \frac{1}{5}$$

So the probability that they're both poisoned is $4/5$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a probability of $\binom{4}{3}\binom{10}{3}^{-1}$ that
all the corrupt pieces end up by the man and a probability of $\binom{6}{3}\binom{10}{3}^{-1}$
that they end up by the woman. So a probability of: $$1-\left[\binom{4}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\right]\binom{10}{3}^{-1}=\frac{4}{5}$$
that both are poisoned.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the desired probability is equivalent to counting the number of ways to obtain either 1 or 2 poisoned candies from a subset of 4, divided by the total number of ways to select 3 poisonous candies out of 10.  This is a sum over a suitable hypergeometric distribution.